# What is the better form to animate on Unity 3D?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I would like animate a object similar 3D sequence diagram using Unity 3D. I don´t know what is better form to animate, if Animation or Animator...

So, I do a preview on Power Point https://youtu.be/tgfPIT47xGY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Animation vs Animator:**

The Animation component is an old component used for animation in our legacy animation system. It remains in Unity for backwards compatibility but you should not use it for new projects. Use the up-to-date Animator component instead. **[SOURCE](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MecanimFAQ.html)**

**Use the [Animation Editor View](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html) for this.**

To animate Game Objects in Unity, the object or objects need an Animator Component attached. This Animator Component must reference an Animator Controller, which in turn contains references to one or more Animation Clips.

When using the Animation View to begin animating a GameObject in Unity, these items will be automatically created, attached and set-up for you.  **[SOURCE](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Though slumtrimpet is obviously right, I can't see why you might need animations to create something like the video you shown. Why don't just use sequential instantiates with the help of coroutines or simple timers?

Comment: Sure... that sounds a LOT easier.  ;-)

Comment: Using coroutine, yes, why not?